# Find logarithm of matrix in diagonalform

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, logarithms, diagonalization, matrix-exponential

I'm trying to decide whether there is a matrix $A \in \text{Mat}(2, \mathbb{R})$ with

$$e^A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I was already able to diagonalise the matrix into

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix} = S^{-1} \cdot \text{diag}(0, 2) \cdot S \hspace{30pt} \text{with} \hspace{30pt} S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. What could be the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative: $e^A$ cannot have a vanishing eigenvalue; in fact it is always invertible and the inverse is $e^{-A}$. So the matrix $A$ does not exists

Comment: Thank you really much. This is a neat solution. Do you have an idea how to decide in the case $e^A \stackrel{!}{=} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Use the remark of José Carlos Santos: $ \det e^A=e^{\textrm{Tr}A}>0$

Answer (score 1):

There is no such matrix. If there was a matrix $B$ such that $e^B=A$, then\begin{align}0&=\det A\\&=\det e^B\\&=e^{\operatorname{tr} B}.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. Till now I didn't know about the trace formula. Is there an intuitive explanation for this? For now I'm accepting @DiegoG7's solution, since it only used the non-singularity of matrix-exponentials.

Comment: If $A$ is upper triangular, the entries of the main diagonal of $e^A$ are the $e^{a_{ii}}$'s and therefore its determinant is$$\prod_{i=1}^ne^{a_{ii}}=\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ii\right)=e^{\operatorname{tr}A}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do we know that $e^B$ is upper triangular?

Comment: And don't understand you question. There was no $B$ in my comment.

Comment: I'm also looking for the existence of the logarithm of $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Can this approach be used here?

Comment: Oh, excuse me. "If $A$ is upper triangle.." why can we assume that $A$ is upper triangle?

Comment: We can't. But *every* square matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: This does makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Concerning your new question, I suggest that you post it as such.